# Will pods running on a PreferNoSchedule node migrate to an untainted node?

Tags: kubernetes

If a single Kubernetes cluster is built and runs some number of pods, however the single node carries a `PreferNoSchedule` taint, it would would make sense to migrate these pods and workloads to more suitable, untainted nodes if they are added to the cluster.

Will this happen automatically in >= 1.6 or will it need to be triggered? How is it triggered?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, there will be no action triggered towards the kube-scheduler to schedule pods even though a new worker is added to a cluster.

For the pods to be moved to a new worker, we need to trigger a new pod scheduling requirement.

Simple solution would be to scale down to 0 and scale up to the needed number of pods for each deployment.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=<expected_replica_num> deployment <deployment_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this doesn't happen automatically with node taints. You can trigger it using `kubectl rollout restart deployment/<name>`.

I was unable to find sufficient literature for this in official Kubernetes documentation. The best I could find is [kubernetes-sigs/descheduler](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler#descheduler-for-kubernetes)